# User Cannot resolve symbol 'buildNumberSeq' Maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-plugin

I have this pom.xml file which I am trying to optimize the JIB of it. I am trying a couple of things until I came to this problem described in a moment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>Something</groupId>
        <artifactId>rSomething</artifactId>
        <version>Something</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>article</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <name>article</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <description>Something</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.24.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Gateway & Message bus -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Response -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Rest API Docs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-jcache</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Google-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Sonarqube-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <!-- JIB Maven Plugin Configuration -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jib-maven.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <from>
                        <image>openjdk:21-jdk-slim</image>
                    </from>
                    <to>
                        <image>article-module:${project.version}</image>
                    </to>
                    <container>
                        <creationTime>USE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP</creationTime>
                        <jvmFlags>
                            <jvmFlag>-Xms512m</jvmFlag>
                            <jvmFlag>-Xmx1024m</jvmFlag>
                        </jvmFlags>
                        <layers>
                            <layer>
                                <name>dependencies</name>
                                <files>
                                    <include>${project.build.directory}/libs/*.jar</include>
                                </files>
                            </layer>
                            <layer>
                                <name>spring-boot-loader</name>
                                <files>
                                    <include>${project.build.directory}/classes/org/springframework/boot/loader/**</include>
                                </files>
                            </layer>
                            <layer>
                                <name>snapshot-dependencies</name>
                                <files>
                                    <include>${project.build.directory}/libs/*-SNAPSHOT.jar</include>
                                </files>
                            </layer>
                            <layer>
                                <name>application</name>
                                <files>
                                    <include>${project.build.directory}/classes/**</include>
                                    <include>${project.build.directory}/libs/!(*-SNAPSHOT).jar</include>
                                    <include>${project.build.directory}/resources/**</include>
                                </files>
                            </layer>
                        </layers>
                    </container>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-maven.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${springdoc-maven.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>buildnumber</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                            <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                            <format>{0}</format>
                            <items>
                                <item>timestamp</item>
                            </items>
                            <buildNumberPropertyName>buildNumberSeq</buildNumberPropertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.${buildNumberSeq}</finalName>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>sonar</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <sonar.projectKey>Something</sonar.projectKey>
                <sonar.host.url>Something</sonar.host.url>
                <sonar.login>Something</sonar.login>
                <sonar.password>Something</sonar.password>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


    <distributionManagement>
       Something
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

for some reason buildNumberSeq cannot be resolved and I am supressing it at the moment, what am I doing wrong?

for some reason buildNumberSeq cannot be resolved and I am supressing it at the moment, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't seem to be able to reproduce it. What Goal/Lifecycle you are running and what is the exact error message you are getting?